# Renewal of French Residence Permit

Tags: france, residence-cards

My residence permit (talent passport) for France is set to expire at the end of October. I live in Paris. I promptly tried renewal 6 months before expiration but being Covid times the authorities said not to apply at the time but 3-2 months before.

Now when I am applying by sending them an email for an appointment I am not getting a reply. The phone number listed is not being manned. I have absolutely no idea what to do.

What is the procedure when the authorities simply are not responding?

Comment: Paris as in Paris proper (département 75) or the broader Paris region? For Paris, it seems there is a website to make an appointment: https://www.ppoletrangers.interieur.gouv.fr/?motif=rensej Which phone number did you try? At which time of the day? If it is possible at all, email is rarely the main contact point/regular procedure for official business. You can also show up at the *préfecture* (be warned, it might be necessary to show up very early to secure a spot in the waiting line).

Comment: There is also a contact form at https://www.prefecturedepolice.interieur.gouv.fr/Demarches/Particulier/Ressortissants-etrangers/Ressortissants-etrangers/Titres-de-sejour-Nous-contacter/Nous-contacter-service-de-l-immigration-professionnelle-qualifiee

Comment: The first one I know. It say "Nous ne sommes pas en mesure de traiter votre demande.
Nous vous invitons à téléphoner au numéro suivant pour nous permettre d'étudier votre situation"

Comment: And what's this phone number? Is it the 34 30?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to [contact the relevant office](https://www.prefecturedepolice.interieur.gouv.fr/Demarches/Particulier/Ressortissants-etrangers/Ressortissants-etrangers/Titres-de-sejour-Nous-contacter) and make an appointment:

- [Website](https://www.ppoletrangers.interieur.gouv.fr/?motif=rensej) (presently not working apparently)
- Calling the 34 30 between 9 am and 4 pm (maybe you tried that already?)
- Showing up between 8:30 and 4 or 4:30 (actually you need to show up early and line up to be sure to be let in before closing time)

There is also a [contact form](https://www.prefecturedepolice.interieur.gouv.fr/Demarches/Particulier/Ressortissants-etrangers/Ressortissants-etrangers/Titres-de-sejour-Nous-contacter/Nous-contacter-service-de-l-immigration-professionnelle-qualifiee), specifically for qualified immigrants but I assume it's redirected to an email account and might not necessarily be more successful than what you already tried.

Do allow for the fact that August is a very slow month in France, especially in Paris. I would retry next week and then show up early in the morning.